# Convert AJAX PHP object to string and echo results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following php object(??? new to this). It is being sent through from my page via AJAX and was sent over as JSON. I'm decoding it and trying to echo the results, but all I get is NULL. In Firebug, everything in the POST widow shows up fine, but nothing in the RESPONSE (which I assume is where I'm supposed to look?)

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$res = json_decode($_POST['apiresponse'], true);
echo $res;
```

- The JSON object was passed to the above PHP file (also stringified before passing)
- JSON was decoded and saved as $res variable
- Everything shows fine in the Firebug POST window

**How do I convert this into a PHP variable (string) that I can return to my original PHP page, and**

**How do I send / call the variable back?****

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the json string that's in $_POST['apiresponse'], it might not be valid json hence it's not getting decoded and you're getting a null.

Comment: Do you see it if you use var_dump() or print_r() instead of echo?

Comment: Hi, I did try using var_dump and print_r and all I get is Array(0).

Comment: Not sure how to paste code into this section, but the I've also taken a different approach and it's currently pulling the Facebook name, stringifying it and sending it through AJAX. On the $_POST['apiresponse'] with it setup this way it is still NULL. But, I do see my name in the POST box with only text and no other characters. Nothing in the RESPONSE box either...

Comment: suggest checking using [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) just in case....

Comment: can you add an `echo $_POST['apiresponse']` (or simply the contents of the post variable from firebug) here? here are a few common examples for illegal json: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-3308

Comment: If you want an exact solution, please put some effort in your question. No one can help you on the basis of assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this was not the case: (skip down!)**
how do you pass the variables from javascript on to php? 
i'm really just guessing here, but it sounds a lot like you have something along the lines of

`$.ajax( "/my-api-thing.php", { data: { "apiresponse": "some_value", "more":"things" } }).success(...);`

IF this is the case then you are only expecting json as a result from the php script, but *you're not actually sending a json object as a request*, but normal http parameters.

you would then just write something like this in php:

`$someVariable = $_POST["apiresponse"]`

(btw: this would be the "normal" way to do it, sending json to the server is not all that common)

---

**updated guess**

i've verified the json you're posting with this file:

```
<form type="textarea" method="post">
<textarea name="apiresult" style="width: 400px;height:200px;">
    {"id":"-------","name":"Aaron ----------","first_name":"Aaron","last_name":"----","link":"http://www.facebook.com/-------","username":"-----","birthday":"05/06/1949","location":{"id":"-----","name":"Los Angeles, California"},"gender":"male","email":"------","timezone":-8,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2011-10-22T18:40:02+0000"}
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<br>


<?php

if( isset( $_POST["apiresult"] ) ){
    echo "<pre>"; 
    echo $apiresult; 
    echo "\n----\n"; 
    print_r( json_decode( $_POST["apiresult"] ) ); 
    echo "</pre>"; 
}

?>
```

so the json_decode doesn't seem to be the problem at all.

a few other guesses:

1. you have a very old version of php a magic quotes are enabled (run phpinfo to check!)
2. you're using a php framework which does some preprocessing on post variables

to pinpoint the problem, can you run an `echo $_POST["apiresponse"];` just before the `json_decode` to see if the output differs from the output?

Comment: $.ajax({ 
        url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/facebook.php",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: 'false',
        data: JSON.stringify(apiresponse),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data);
        }
    });

Comment: The above is how my current ajax code reads. New to this... thanks!

Comment: i see, so you are indeed posting json :) 
can you do the following: `alert( JSON.stringify(apiresponse) );` and post what it says here?

Comment: {"id":"-------","name":"Aaron ----------","first_name":"Aaron","last_name":"----","link":"http://www.facebook.com/-------","username":"-----","birthday":"05/06/1949","location":{"id":"-----","name":"Los Angeles, California"},"gender":"male","email":"------","timezone":-8,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2011-10-22T18:40:02+0000"}

Comment: please checkout the original post, i've updated it with a new guess :)

Comment: Hey Kritzikratzi, thanks for your feedback and help! I checked and magic quotes were turned on, so they're off now, but still nothing. The update you posted above makes complete sense, so it does look like everything is being passed to my php file (AJAX) and the json decode is working properly. I just don't know how to use that PHP in my original page? Just trying to call back variables to create a WordPress user. Would WordPress be preprocessing on post variables? Thanks!

Comment: you already have it in a variable, `$res`. i suppose you want something along the lines of `wp_create_user( $res["username"], "defaultpassword", $res["email"] );` and after that a redirect: `header( "Location: someFile.php" );`. However, I have to agree with @Imran. As a general problem solving strategy always try to break it up into small tests to find out where your problem lies. (e.g. make one test for creating the user, another for getting the data from facebook, then combine them). the more precise you can formulate your problem the more people will be able and willing to help you!

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

"NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit."
```

Check the depth of "$_POST['apiresponse']".